# Extract the contents of dynamically generated QLineEdit objects in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Currently I am working on a Qt application written with pyqt5 library. The application is reading different data from a PostgreSQL DB and populates specific `QLabels` or `QLineEdits` in the GUI. On a specific part of the application I would like to create a functionality where the user can modify it's data in the database (first/last name, phone number, email address). I have the block of code which generates the labels and the text boxes and inserts the proper data from the DB.

```py
        def open_update_account():
            # Change to dynamic query in implementation
            postgres_conn.POSTGRES_CURSOR.execute(f"SELECT customer_id, username, first_name, last_name, phone, email_address FROM customers WHERE username = 'pesho'")
            result = postgres_conn.POSTGRES_CURSOR.fetchone()
            
            update_user_settings_groupbox = QGroupBox("Update Account Settings")
            update_user_settings_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            update_user_settings_layout.addStretch()
            update_user_settings_layout.addSpacing(10)

            text_labels = deque(['ID', 'Username', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone Number', 'Email Address'])
            text_labels_length = len(text_labels)
            
            for i in range(text_labels_length):
                current_text_label = QLabel()
                current_text_label.setText(text_labels.popleft())
                current_text_label.setFont(QFont(fonts[0], 12))

                current_line_edit = QLineEdit()
                current_line_edit.setText(str(result[i]))
                current_line_edit.setFont(QFont(fonts[0], 12))
                current_line_edit.setMaximumWidth(250)
                # Disables user_id and username modification
                if i < 2:
                    current_line_edit.setReadOnly(True)

                update_user_settings_layout.addWidget(current_text_label)
                update_user_settings_layout.addWidget(current_line_edit)
                            
            update_user_settings_layout.addStretch()
            update_user_settings_layout.addSpacing(20)
            
            reset_button = QPushButton()
            reset_button.setText("Reset to defaults")
            reset_button.setFont(QFont(fonts[0], 12))
            reset_button.setFixedWidth(200)
            reset_button.clicked.connect(lambda: open_update_account())
            
            update_user_setting_button = QPushButton()
            update_user_setting_button.setText("Update Info")
            update_user_setting_button.setFont(QFont(fonts[0], 12))
            update_user_setting_button.clicked.connect(lambda: update_user())
            update_user_setting_button.setFixedWidth(200)
            
            update_user_settings_layout.addWidget(reset_button)
            update_user_settings_layout.addWidget(update_user_setting_button)

            update_user_settings_groupbox.setLayout(update_user_settings_layout)

            categories_groupbox.hide()
            main_layout.addWidget(update_user_settings_groupbox, 1, 1)
```

I decided to draw the objects with for loop to reduce a bit the quantity of the code, on every iteration the loop creates one new QLabel and one new QLineEdit, populating them from a deque for the labels and from the database query for the QLineEdit's. Everything seems to be working just perfectly and in the GUI all the objects are displayed properly with the corespoding data from the postgre.

[image]

Then I have two new buttons --> `Reset to defaults` which will call once again `open_update_account` and will populate all the objects with the currently existing data from the DB, basically reseting all the changes that the user has been made. And the `Update Info` button which will save the data from the fields in the database updating the existing table with the changes made by the user. For this functionality I have another function which executes a SQL query and commits the changes in the postgre.

```py
        # Not fully implemented, fucntion is still taking old data from qlineedit's
        user_data = []
        def update_user():
            # Make this query dynamically accepting the username in production
            update_user_query = (f"UPDATE customers SET first_name = %s, last_name = %s, phone = %s, email_address = %s WHERE username = 'pesho'")
            postgres_conn.POSTGRES_CURSOR.execute(update_user_query, (user_data[0], user_data[1], user_data[2], user_data[3]))
            postgres_conn.POSTGRES_CONNECTION.commit()
```

***To the problem:*** I tried to put every QLineEdit object in the `user_data` array appending it with `current_line_edit.text()` and then taking the strings from it to give it to the sql query as input. But, because I am generating the QLineEdit's inside a for loop, basically I have one single variable which generates a new text line on every iteration, so when I am trying to execute the `update_user()` function it reads the *old* contents of the line edits and not the any new changes that the user is making inside the text box. Is there any way I can iterate again though the QLineEdit objects and take theirs contents once I have them generated inside the for loop?

Comment: Append the line edits, not their contents, then access them by using their `text()` when you iterate over the list.

Comment: Post a [mre] including ```current_line_edit.text()```.

Comment: @musicamante Yep, that worked. Thank you very much!

I created the `user_data` array before the function `open_update_account()` and appended the qlineedit's(as object, not theirs contents). Then I just called each index from the array with `.text()` method and it worked perfectly.